# Worldpay extension not working with Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, worldpay

Has anyone tried to use the worldpay extension with magento and got it to work?
For some reason, if installs absolutely fine, shows up in the admin>configuration>sales as a separate payment option and when enabled from there, it shows up on the front end as an option for checkout. However, when it is selected as the option for checkout, it doesn't expand to take the card details, nor does it redirect to worldpay page to take the payment details. What happens instead is that it processes the order without taking any payment whatsoever.
Important thing to note here is, it doesn't show any errors on the page either, when using the native Magento One Page Checkout. However, when we use the TM's Firecheckout extension, it shows an error saying "Failed to load WorldpayJS", which is due to the fact that it is not supported by Firecheckout(confirmed with their developer team).

Details : 
**Magento version 1.9.2.4**

Extension used from :

> https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, Worldpay extension is not the most beautifully written piece of code, and has a lot of compatibility issues with 3rd party extensions. Thus, it is best to avoid it, if possible as their customer service isn't the best in the world anyway. Just stating that I have decided to leave it, as I couldn't find a solution to the problem and they're not really willing to help me (The technical team of Worldpay).